# I'm using Gulp and failing to produce the final development script for production.

Tags: javascript, gulp

So I'm having a slight problem with producing production ready scripts for my project. I'm using gulp to concatenate and minify my css and js, and while the css is working fine the gulp js function isn't generating my final file. Please refer to my code below:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
 return gulp.src([source + 'js/app/**/*.js'])
  .pipe(concat('development.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(source + 'js'))
  .pipe(rename({
   basename: 'production',
   suffix: '-min',
}))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(source + 'js/'))
  .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete', onLast: true }));
});
```

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any tips it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You've got your src after the uglify process. But that is not the way you should be writing a gulpfile. Each task is a logical progression (pipeline) from beginning to end. You should be dealing with your CSS and javascript in entirely separate gulp tasks and then bootstrap them together.

Comment: @MatthewRath you should post an answer with some code in it, sounds like you're on the right track and I wanna give you some free karma

Comment: No karma needed, it's not what i'd consider to be a real question which is why im providing troubleshooting help instead of a flat answer. Also using [source + '<glob>'] seems a bit funky to me... what is `var source` set as? What happens if you just use a hardcoded glob?

Comment: Best advice i can give is to establish a standard way of doing things, dump your gulpfile and package.json in a git repo and re-use it every time. I used [this one](https://github.com/pauldijou/gulp-kickoff) as a base in the past and rehashed / reconfig'd it to my own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your gulpfile. I tested it and it works perfectly.

The only thing I can guess is that your `source` is not set correctly. Did you forget the trailing slash '/' ?

I would suggest 2 things to figure it out. Include node *path* library to check where source is actually pointing to like this:

```
var path = require('path');

// in gulp task ...
path.resolve(path.resolve(source + 'js/app'));
```

Make sure it points where you think it does.

Secondly, you could use gulp-debug to establish that any files are found:

```
npm install gulp-debug
```

Then

```
var debug = require('gulp-debug');


// in gulp task ...

return gulp.src([source + 'js/app/**/*.js'])
           .pipe(concat('development.js'))
           .pipe(debug())
           .pipe(gulp.dest(source + 'js'))
           .pipe(debug())
           // etc.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey @chriskelly thanks so much for the answer. I have included the trailing / in my source variable, and I know this isn't the problem as my 'styles' task, which essentially does the same thing as the js function, works fine. I installed gulp-debug and 0 files were detected. I couldn't generate a source map for the js task either. Excuse my ignorance, I'm relatively new to Gulp. Another thing that may be of interest, when I run the JS function it says Finished 'js' but doesn't run the notification 'scripts task complete'. Does this indicate the function ISN'T Completing a task?

Comment: OK. Maybe a silly question, but are there any js files in js/app? Like I said, your code, unchanged works for me

Comment: Hey Chris, no there isn't.

Comment: my folder structure is as folllows:
assets/js/----app (will contain production ready JS files after Gulp comp)
               '---vendor (contains various js files ready for compiling)
Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Based on *additional infomation in the comments* I realise you are generating JS files in a separate process ...

gulp is asynchronous by default. What this boils down to is that all functions try to run at the same time - if you want a specific order it must be by design. This is great because it's very fast but can be a headache to work with.

### Problem

Here is what's basically happening:

```
// SOME TASK THAT SHOULD BE RUN FIRST
gulp.task('copy-vendor-files-to-tempfolder', function (done) {
    // copy files to vendor folder
    done()
})

// SOME TASKS THAT DEPEND ON FIRST TASK
gulp.task('complile-styles', function () { /* independent task */ })
gulp.task('concat-vendor-files', function () { /* concat files in vendor folder. depends on vendor files existing */ })

// GENERAL TASK WHICH STARTS OTHERS
gulp.task('ready', ['copy-vendor-files-to-tempfolder', 'compile-styles', 'concat-vendor-files])
```

When you try to run:

```
$ gulp ready 
GULP TASK WILL FAIL! Folder is being created at the same time!!
NOWHERE TO COPY FILES!
```

### Solution

There are many solutions but the following module has come in handy for me again and again:

```
npm install run-sequence
```

Then in your gulpfile.js:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence')

gulp.task('ready', function (done) {
    runSequence(
        'create-folders', // do this first,
        [
            'copy-css-files',
            'copy-html-files'
        ], // do these AFTER but in parallel
        done   // callback when ready
    )
})
```

This will guarantee the folder exists when you try to run the other functions.

In your specific case, you should make sure the task that concatenates the JS files is run after the task that copies them out of vendor.

*Note:* I'm leaving other answer because it contains useful help for debugging similar issues.

HTH!

Comment: @TimFernandez: Does this make sense to you? and did it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks again Chris, I'm just testing now. Also did u mean "npm install run-sequence"?

Comment: This does make sense, if the folders AND files are being generated asynchronously then the task should fail. However I'm not using gulp to create the folders, only the compiled files inside the 'app' folder. Would it help you to have a look at my complete file structure?

Comment: Sure I can look. Folder creation was meant as example though. Applies equally to copying vendor files or whatever else you are doing. Not having gulpfile I had to make example up.